# Method to return an array element at a given position?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method which takes an int argument and returns the element of an array given if the passed int argument is less than the array length. I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Code:

```
String[] fruits = {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","oct"};



public String getStr( int pos ){

    String str;

    if( pos <= fruits.length){

        for( int i=0; i < fruits.length; ++i){          
            if(fruits[i] == pos){

                str = fruits[pos];

            }//IF
        }
    }//IF
    else{
        str = null;
    }
    return str;
}//METOD
```

Comment: `pos` vs `position`. Which one is it? Also, What do you think `fruits[i]` does?

Comment: if( pos <= fruits.length){ return fruits[pos-1]; }

Comment: method should return void either any data type not both  :public void String getStr

Comment: if(fruits[i] == position)  fruits[i] return string and pos is integer how u r comparing this ..?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, now I know what I was doing wrong, and how I should be coding it. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Array data structure provides **random access** based on array index. Therefore, you dont need to iterate over the array until you reach the required position. You can access it directly.
2. In Java (like most programming languages), **arrays are 0-indexed**. This means that for an array of size n, the indices of the array will vary from 0 to n-1. Therefore, any index <0 or  index>=n will result in ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception.

Keeping in mind these things, the following code will work as desired: (assuming that 'pos' represents number based on 0-indexed counting)

```
String[] fruits = {"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","oct"};
public String getStr(int pos) {
    if( pos < fruits.length && pos > -1){
        return fruits[pos];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why return when its void method?

Comment: Sorry about that. Directly copied from question code and did not pay attention.

Comment: that would just depend on how you use 'pos'. I am assuming that count of pos starts from 0.

Comment: Yes, it does start from 0

Answer (score 1):

An array element can be accessed by the index. So you just have to check if the given index is within the array's bounds and then either return the array element or `null`. This can be written in a single line:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

So, your method will look like this:

```
public String getStr(int pos) {
    return (pos >= 0 && pos < fruits.length) ? fruits[pos] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that pos wich is index of array is valid then send element else null.

```
return (pos >-1 && pos < fruits.length) ? fruits[pos] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to iterate. Arrays are there so that you can find an element by index.

Just use

```
if( pos <= fruits.length){
    str = fruits[pos];
}//IF
else{
    str = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void String getStr(int pos) {
    String str;

    if (pos >= 0 && pos < fruits.length)
    {
        return fruits[pos];
    }
    else
    {
       return null;
    }
} // METHOD
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself these questions:

- How do you get a specific element in an array?
- How would you check if the `pos` parameter is too large or too small (hint: use length)

just think about those two questions and try to put them into code. Others have already given the answer (which they shouldn't have because you didn't request it), but still ask yourself these questions to improve your understanding of the situation.